# efficiency of pow(num,2)?

Tags: c++, math, loops, floating-point

I need to calculate squares of floats many times.(to the order of 10^8)

Which is better (as time is a huge constraint) :

```
 pdt=pow(num,2);

      OR

 pdt=num*num
```

Or are they really same?

**Edit: On checking both styles on reasonably large input, my processor gave contradictory results.**

Comment: Profile it and see.

Comment: Share the program you used for profiling, it's possible that the compiler is optimizing out the calculation altogether.

Comment: What does "contradictory results" mean?

Comment: @Xymostech: sometimes less time taken by pow and sometimes otherwise.
i dont know what "profiling" is. I just noted the time taken for code to run.

Comment: Oh, so not necessarily "contradictory", just "ambiguous". Is your program doing anything else? Try making a problem that only runs that one line, a large number of times, and see which one runs faster that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`num*num` will be at least as fast as `pow(num, 2)` on any non-perverse C/C++ implementation, because there is no implementation of `pow` without at least one floating-point multiplication or more time-consuming operation.

Answer (score 6):

Using gcc with no optmisations num * num is faster as `pow` incurs a function call. At `-O2` they output identical asm (for x86):

```
float numpow(float x){
    return pow(x, 2);
}

float mulpow(float x){
    return x*x;
}

compiled with g++ -S -O2 -c 

__Z6numpowf:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    mulss   %xmm0, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:

...
__Z6mulpowf:
Leh_func_begin2:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp3:
    mulss   %xmm0, %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Yup, gcc implements `pow` and other math functions as compiler intrinsics, so that's to be expected (also leads to interesting effects when debugging with gdb).